# How to import (or use tokenVocab) for a grammar file in a different directory/package?

Tags: antlr4

I have two grammar files in directories like this:

```
 +- antlr4
     +- common
     |   +- Numbers.g4
     +- lang
         +- Lang.g4
```

Inside `Lang.g4`, I tried to do:

```
  grammar Lang;

  options {
      tokenVocab = common.Numbers;
  }
```

But I get an error:

```
 cannot find tokens file <PROJECT_LOCATION>/target/generated-sources/antlr4/common.Numbers.tokens
```

Am I limited to just putting all grammar and lexer files in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not limited.

You should have a `Numbers.token` file in the `Lang.g4` grammar directory. After that you can use `tokenVocab` by the following way:

```
options {
      tokenVocab = Numbers;
}
```

For placing generated files to a custom location you can use `-o` command line parameter. See here: [ANTLR Tool Command Line Options](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/4.6/doc/tool-options.md).

Comment: I think the issue is just the Antlr Intellij plugin. It shows errors, which don't happen when I actually generate the parsers.

Comment: `.tokens` are not parsed with the same rules as `lexer grammar`. I get `bad token def` everywhere